# What is the best approach for Java, Spring and Angularjs web-app?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to develop a web app using following technologies: Maven, Java, Hibernate, Spring ( core, mvc, security, data), Bootstrap 3, AngularJs. I am wondering what is the best approch between the both. My question is about how to organize the web part. I have many html page in my application ( homepage.html, login.html, usermanagement.html, profil.hml, project.html) :

1.I want to use a real single page application where. I have one main file with ng-view tag and use a routeProvider to switch to partials. For instance, i could write the following code

```
    myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/homepage.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          }).
          when('/login/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });

  }]);
```

2. The second option i have is to make multiple single page application. I this case, each page will be rendered using spring mvc. In each page i will have a angularjs controller. For instance, the following Spring MVC controller renders the home page.

   @Controller
   @RequestMapping( "/" )
   public class HomePageController{

   ```
   @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
   public String index() {

       return "homepage";
   }
   ```

   }

For the home page, i will have the config as :

```
 myhomePageApp.config(['$routeProvider',
          function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
              when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'nothing to display',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
              }).
              when('/contact/', {
                // display contact info in a div on home page
                templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html', 
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
              }).
              otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
              });

      }]);
```

So it's page will be a single page application. 
Thank you for reading and for your suggestions.

Comment: What is your question? It's possible to create a SPA with the technologies you chose. It's also possible to create a MPA. There is no "best" design. Both have their pros and cons. Choose what you prefer.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your comment. I want to know theirs pro and cons before i decide.

Comment: I am new in AngularJs so i don't have experience to make good choice with this technology

Answer (score 0):

For your proposed stack, consider a conceptual split of your web-application into a Java, Hibernate, Spring back-end and an AngularJS, Bootstrap front-end.

This way, you can use something like [Spring Boot](http://yeoman.io/) to help you setup the back-end. This will create a Maven project for you with all dependencies and a good project layout.

You can then use any of the front-end scaffolding tools available for creating the AngularJS app. [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) is a good tool to get you started with AngularJS and Bootstrap. It also creates a Grunt build file which automates the build process for you.

You should then only implement service endpoints in your back-end and create the entire UI in the front-end app. You can then use Maven/Grunt to combine these two into one deployable application, or even decide to host them separately.

Comment: Great i will check it. But is it better to create a spa or a mpa ?

Comment: It's hard to say which is better. In my experience it is hard to create an entire web application as a single MPA. For example, you might have certain landing pages where (potential) clients arrive, which are purely static, or password retrieval pages, which have some functionality. For those it would not make sense to load your entire SPA (also bad for PageSpeed ranking). The part where your clients use the actual functions of your app should probably be implemented as an SPA.

Comment: Ok thanks. I catch so you think it's better and simpler to create a multiple page application